# Error correction in reading QR codes

Tags: decode, qr-code

I am working with a client to promote their site via QR Codes.  They would like to put a QR code on floor decal in a grocery store.

I am concerned about how well this will perform as the floor decal is worn down over time via walking, spills, etc.

One of the considerations would be how its printed (material and ink) and the size of the QR code itself.  But how do the decoding algorithms error correct?  Is this even an issue that needs to be considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an implementation of Reed-Solomon coding, so it's fairly robust. The application used to generate a QR code for you can be configured, see a blog post here:

http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2010/10/qr-codes-and-error-correction/

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of [the post on error correction](http://shkspr.mobi/blog/index.php/2010/10/qr-codes-and-error-correction/).

For best results, you need to set the Error Correction to "H" that's "Hight".

That will allow up to 30% of the code to be damaged.

Note: The three corner squares are the most crucial - once they are obscured, most scanners won't be able to see the code.